# Check for Partial Match in 1 List With Partial Match Another List - Possible With List Comprehension?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, match, list-comprehension

somewhat of a python/programming newbie here.

I have written code that does what I need it to:

```
import re
syns = ['professionals|experts|specialists|pros', 'repayed|payed back', 'ridiculous|absurd|preposterous', 'salient|prominent|significant' ]
new_syns = ['repayed|payed back', 'ridiculous|crazy|stupid', 'salient|prominent|significant', 'winter-time|winter|winter season', 'professionals|pros']

def pipe1(syn):
    # Find first word/phrase in list element up to and including the 1st pipe
    r = r'.*?\|'
    m = re.match(r, syn)
    m = m.group()
    return m

def find_non_match():
    # Compare 'new_syns' with 'syns' and create new list from non-matches in 'new_syns'
    p = '@#&'   # Place holder created
    joined = p.join(syns)
    joined = p + joined   # Adds place holder to beginning of string too
    non_match = []
    for syn in new_syns:
        m = pipe1(syn)
        m = p + m
        if m not in joined:
            non_match.append(syn)
    return non_match

print find_non_match()
```

*Printed output:*

```
['winter-time|winter|winter season']
```

The code checks if the word/phrase up to and including the first pipe for each element in `new_syns` is a match for the same partial match in `syns` list. The purpose of the code is to actually find the non-matches and then append them to a new list called `non_match`, which it does.

However, I am wonder if it is possible to achieve the same purpose, but in much fewer lines using list comprehension. I have tried, but I am not getting what I want exactly. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
import re
syns = ['professionals|experts|specialists|pros', 'repayed|payed back', 'ridiculous|absurd|preposterous', 'salient|prominent|significant' ]
new_syns = ['repayed|payed back', 'ridiculous|crazy|stupid', 'salient|prominent|significant', 'winter-time|winter|winter season', 'professionals|pros']

def pipe1(syn):
    # Find first word/phrase in list element up to and including the 1st pipe
    r = r'.*?\|'
    m = re.match(r, syn)
    m = '@#&' + m.group() # Add unusual symbol combo to creatte match for beginning of element
    return m

non_match = [i for i in new_syns if pipe1(i) not in '@#&'.join(syns)]
print non_match
```

*Printed output:*

```
['winter-time|winter|winter season', 'professionals|pros'] # I don't want 'professionals|pros' in the list
```

The caveat in the list comprehension is that when joining `syns` with `@#&`, I don't have the `@#&` at the beginning of the now joined string, whereas in my original code above that does not use the list comprehension I add `@#&` to the beginning of the joined string. The result is that `'professionals|pros'` have slipped through the net. But I don't know how to pull that off within the list comprehension.

So my question is "Is this possible with the list comprehension?".

Comment: Why are you using `|` on only one side in the regular expression? What if its an edge condition?

Comment: Well, It would work just as well if I used a look ahead assertion for the pipe and only matched the first word/phrase up to (but not including) the first pipe. The match is for the all content before the first pipe, that is the important thing here. I do not want to match anything after the first pipe in each element in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
non_match = [i for i in new_syns if not any(any(w == s.split("|")[0] 
                                                for w in i.split("|")) 
                                            for s in syns)]
```

This doesn't use regular expressions, but does give the result

```
non_match == ['winter-time|winter|winter season']
```

The list includes any items from `new_syns` where none (`not any`) of the `'|'`-separated words `w` are in `any` of the first word (`split("|")[0]`) of each synonym group `s` from `syns`

Comment: I need the match to be only for the first word/phrase up to the pipe for each element in `syns`. So for the first index of `syns`, only `professionals|` in that index should be a match, and not `experts`, '`specialists`, and `pros`. That being the case, if I add `'experts|specialists'` to the end of the `new_syns` list, that should show up in my `non_match` list because it does not match the first word in any of the elements in `syns`

Comment: Ah, I see; I have made a suitable alteration.

Comment: Perfect - thank you. Now I got to study that nested double `any` method until it sinks in :-)